# "Class already defined" while using typings in python

Tags: python, typing

I'm building a little program but I'm trying to make it more easily expandable for the future (without the need of much refactoring). I'm experimenting with things I have never used before like typings.
I have a small typings file that looks like this (called typings.py)

```py
from typing import (
    Union,
    Any,
    Optional
)

from typing import ForwardRef as ref

CustomLevel = ref("levels.level.CustomLevel")
OfficialLevel = ref("levels.level.OfficialLevel")

__all__ = (
    "Union",
    "Any",
    "Optional",

    "CustomLevel",
    "OfficialLevel",
)
```

I also have a level.py file under `./levels/`. In the file I have a base class but also a `CustomLevel` and `OfficialLevel`. At the top of level.py I am importing the CustomLevel typing. The issue is I am getting an error saying:

```
class already defined (line 5)
```

because the import of the CustomLevel type is clashing with definition of the CustomLevel class, like so:

```py
from ..typings import (
    CustomLevel
)

class CustomLevel(): #<--- erros here since 'customlevel' is already defined
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    def somefunc(self) -> CustomLevel:
        pass
```

I am actually using an already existing library as a sort of "guide". What I mean is I am looking at the code of the library, because I think it's pretty good code, and using some of the features I think will be helpful in my program (like typings). In their library they do exactly what I am doing where they import a type from their typing file, and then create a class of the same name. In theirs they don't get an error though.
The Library is [this](https://github.com/NeKitDS/gd.py). It happens in a lot of the python scrips but a short one is the [comment.py](https://github.com/NeKitDS/gd.py/blob/master/gd/comment.py). At the top of the file, from `gd.typing`, `Comment` is imported. Not too much further down `Comment` is created as a class. Like I said, this library has no issues.
In their typing.py file the only extra bit is:

```
def __forward_ref_repr__(self: ref) -> str:
    return str(self.__forward_arg__)


setattr(ref, "__repr__", __forward_ref_repr__)
```

I have tried adding this but it doesn't make any difference. I am using VSCode with pylint which could very well be the case but at the moment I have other errors which won't allow me to run the script to test.

Comment: This appears to be a linter warning, not an actual error.  It's just pointing out that it's useless to import something, and then overwrite that name with something else without ever using the original version.

Comment: Since it's coming up under the "problems" tab I would assume it would be an issue but you may well be right. Im going to see if I can fix the other errors soon so I can check that.

Comment: Linter warnings are quite useful in showing your "problems" even if not a compile error. Redefining the name is one such problem. You could import it as a different name if necessary. (It's unclear what you are trying to achieve with it)

Comment: I don't think I'm trying to achieve anything with it. I'm doing a little project and while coding it I am trying to learn and use things I haven't done like typings. I'm using that library that I linked to in the my post as a sort of guide. As I said, they import a typing and then create a class of the same name. I don't know if this is good, I was just following it.